# How can I code a contract with permanent all erc20 tokens unlimited approvals exeute transferfrom to a target address which is also set permanent too?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I am actually new to coding solidity and smart contracts here is a code I was able to develop with the help of an AI

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.21;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract TokenTransfer is Ownable {
    address public targetAddress;
    address[] public tokenAddresses;

    modifier onlyTargetAddress() {
        require(msg.sender == targetAddress, "Only the target address can call this function");
        _;
    }

    event TokensTransferred(address indexed tokenAddress, address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 amount);

    constructor(address _targetAddress, address[] memory _tokenAddresses) {
        targetAddress = _targetAddress;
        tokenAddresses = _tokenAddresses;
    }

    function setTargetAddress(address _targetAddress) public onlyOwner {
        targetAddress = _targetAddress;
    }

    function setTokenAddresses(address[] memory _tokenAddresses) public onlyOwner {
        tokenAddresses = _tokenAddresses;
    }

    function approveAndTransferAllTokens() public onlyTargetAddress {
        // Execution of the function
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokenAddresses.length; i++) {
            address tokenAddress = tokenAddresses[i];
            uint256 tokenBalance = IERC20(tokenAddress).balanceOf(msg.sender);
            uint256 allowance = IERC20(tokenAddress).allowance(msg.sender, targetAddress);

            if (tokenBalance > 0 && allowance == 0) {
                IERC20(tokenAddress).approve(targetAddress, tokenBalance);
            }
            if (allowance > 0) {
                IERC20(tokenAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, targetAddress, allowance);
                emit TokensTransferred(tokenAddress, msg.sender, targetAddress, allowance);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I deployed this code to goerli in remix.ide and it worked fine but some developers who said it would be prone to bugs.
Im looking to develop a code where by which the caller upon calling the contract will grant the contract unlimited allowance (The contract is set to approve all erc20 tokens permanently as unlimited and this cant be changed) also before approval the contract will check the balance of said caller for the available balances of the the specified erc20 tokens lets say ["0xTokenAddress1", "0xTokenAddress2", "0xTokenAddress3"]; if the caller doesn't have "0xTokenAddress2" in its balance but has "0xTokenAddress1" "0xTokenAddress3" the contract will skip "0xTokenAddress2" and only ask approval for "0xTokenAddress1" "0xTokenAddress3" (in order to minimize Gas as low as possible for only the tokens available in the balance of the callers address). Lets also say we can set the target address where the contract will execute transferfrom to and this can be set permanently as "0xTargetAddress" (This will be the address the contract will transfer all erc20 tokens to in one go after approval.

SUMMARY: The caller calls the contract, the contract checks for balances of the specified token addresses from the token arrays and asks unlimited allowance for the available tokens, Once approved the contract transfers all erc20 tokens to the target address. My question now is, is the above summary possible to execute? And If it is How will it be written?

I tried AI and was expecting better results